# Home made base converter with Cocoa (swift)

Tags: swift

In order to get familiar with swift language and Cocoa, I decided to create a little base convert,  from base 2 to 10 first, then I'd like adding some other bases like 16 and 5.
Still I can't make it work properly : [Running App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CqNEm.png)
[View Controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EsiqI.png) [4 digits and more](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HLqfl.png) [debugger removes the whitespace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XhuIm.png)

```
import Cocoa

class ViewController: NSViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var baseFrom: NSPopUpButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var baseTo: NSPopUpButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var myBase: NSTextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var testLabel: NSTextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var resultLabel: NSTextField!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override var representedObject: Any? {
        didSet {
            // Update the view, if already loaded.
        }
    }

    @IBAction func convertButton(_ sender: Any)
    {
        let popUpChoice = baseFrom.titleOfSelectedItem! //the choice of the popUpButton (only 2 possible yet)
        var index : Int = 0 //useless
        var baseToConvert : Int = 0 //stocks the 10 base
        var myBaseFrom : Int // the original base (here : 2)
        var isOk : Bool = true //check that the base is a 2 binary base
        var test : Int

        if popUpChoice == "2"
        {
            let setBase  = myBase.stringValue
            var correctedReverseBase : String = ""
            for char in setBase
            {
                if char == "0" || char == "1" || char == "\0"
                {
                    index += 1 // useless (needed for tests)
                    correctedReverseBase += String(char)

                }
                else
                {
                    resultLabel.stringValue = "recommencer" // base not okay !
                    test = Int(char.unicodeScalars[char.unicodeScalars.startIndex].value)
                    if test > 32 && test < 127
                    {
                        isOk = false
                    }

                }
            }
            myBaseFrom = 1
            let reverseBase = String(correctedReverseBase.reversed())
//            let correctedReverseBase = String(reverseBase.filter { !" \n\t\r".contains($0) })

            if isOk // if the base is correct
            {
                for char in reverseBase
                {
                    baseToConvert += Int(String(char))! * myBaseFrom // convert form 2 to 10
                    myBaseFrom *= 2
                }
                resultLabel.stringValue = String(baseToConvert) //show result
                //                resultLabel.stringValue = String(reverseBase)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The app is running smoothly as long as I don't add binary numbers longer than 4 digit (it converts 101 to 5 as you can see in my second picture).

The thing I don't understand is, why it simply stops working after 4 digits. 
I think the problem might be coming from the NsTextField, but I did not find anything "useful" in it's settings or documentation.
Pretty sure it's a stupid mistake, still it seems I cannot get rid of it without your help.
Thank you in advance,
Artiom

EDIT : In case someone cares : NSTextField was adding an 'á' (160 ascii character) so I add to add a condition in the loop to ignore such characters.
I changed the code.

Comment: As far as I tested your code, it works even when I entered more than 4 binary digits into the `NSTextField`. Please write more precise description about _stops working after 4 digits_.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I added an example with 4 digits in my main post

Comment: Seems not yet, as for now.

Comment: Sorry, got a problem with code indenting.
It should appear now

Comment: Seems your NSTextField is putting an extra whitespace. Check the settings of the NSTextView or remove all whitespaces before you set `myBase.stringValue` to `setBase`.

Comment: Set a breakpoint, single-step, inspect the variables. It's called “debugging.”

Comment: My bad, I always forget the debugger, I add the line :                     correctedReverseBase += String(char)
in my second If condition to remove whitespaces,
It does remove it (see debugger pictures), but it still does not return the expected result.

Comment: The problem comes from my isOkey var, when I remove it, it works, I'try adding more precise conditions (to tolerate \t and \n...)
Thank you all for your help.

Comment: One more, this app seems to be just a practice, so you would not internationalize it. But when in some other locale, macOS uses `.` or `,` for thousand separator. You may need to include `.` and `,` into the _to tolerate \t and \n..._ list. And U+00A0(160 in decimal) is NO-BREAK SPACE in Unicode, it's not `á`.

Comment: If you look at my new code, you'll see that I had a new variable "test" to get the ascii value of "char", when I inputed 1101 in my NSTextField, the value of test (debugger) became "á" (which is the the character 160 from the extended ascii table) and it's at this moment that my program entered the else condition.
for , and . separator, do you mean that some people separate some bases with  . or , ? Like 101, 010 ?

Comment: Please include `@OOPer` in a reply to me. First your `test` in your updated code holds **Unicode code point** of the character, not _ascii value_. Second, Swift uses Unicode as its basis of `String` type, not ascii. Third, _the extended ascii_ does not make sense. There are many encodings called as _extended ascii_ and in some of them, 160 represents NO-BREAK SPACE as well as in Unicode. And the last, **_do you mean that some people separate some bases with . or , ?_** It is not _people_ who separates digits with `.` or `,`. It's macOS that does it. Try with your Mac set to another language.

Comment: [World wide thousand separators here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/806-0169/overview-9/index.html), [General description of _extended ASCII_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_ASCII), [Another example of extended ASCII](https://www.ascii-code.com). [Unicode code chart including U+00A0(=160)](https://unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0080.pdf).

Comment: Thanks for your advises @OOPer (and sorry for my late reply, had to send my MacBook back to Apple :( ) I will apply to my future code.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you reinvent the wheel?

Swift has an API to convert a string to a number with different bases.

```
let myBaseFrom = 2
if let result = Int(myBase.stringValue, radix: myBaseFrom) {
    resultLabel.stringValue = String(result)
} else {
    resultLabel.stringValue = "Conversion failed"
}
```

By the way `101` base 2 **is** 5

Comment: Thank you for your answer, first I know that I can use your method to convert bases, but what's the point ? I don't want to make a base converter for personal usage, I just want to practice with Swift.
Also I know that 101 is 5 in base 2, the problem is that for 3 digits or less, the converter works, but after 3 digits, it stops working and returns aberrant results.